# C program is not printing '@' character

Tags: c

I'm trying to print out a random number of "@" characters but my code is printing out random "\\" instead. Don't know whats going on here just need a little help.

```
int ran,i;
ran = 1 + (rand() % 25 + 1 );
for (i = 0; i < ran; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", "@");
    }
printf("\n");
```

Comment: `"@"` is not a character, it's a string. `'@'` is a character.

Answer (score 5):

`"@"` is not a `char` literal, which `%c` expects, it is a string literal. Use single quotes for `char` literals:

```
printf("%c", '@');
```

Comment: Or use a string but tell `printf()` to expect a string: `printf("%s", "@")` — or use `putchar('@')` to output single characters (and `putchar('\n')` after the loop).

Comment: @Jonathan: correct, but I didn't want to confuse anyone. <g>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that'll work:-

```
int ran;
char i;
ran = 1 + (rand() % 25 + 1 );
for (i = 0; i < ran; i++)
   {
       printf("%c", i);
   }
```

Comment: That will **not** print a number of '@' characters.

Comment: i don't get it what he want to do?

Comment: if he want to print only '@' he can simply use :- printf("@"); or puts("@");